# Yum always lists some packages

Tags: fedora, yum

Whenever I use yum to install something it lists the same packages like this:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                         |  951 B  00:00:00     
bumblebee                                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
chromium-el6                                                                               | 1.9 kB  00:00:00     
churchyard-chromium-russianfedora-tested                                                   | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
```

Except up to 10 packages. What purpose does this serve and can I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a list of the repositories that `yum` is currently using.  You can get a description of each using:

```
$ yum repolist
```

You can remove this by lowering the debug level of `yum`:

```
$ yum -d 1 install <a package>
```

To make it permanent, find `debuglevel` in `/etc/yum.conf` and set it to `1` (I believe the default is `2`).  If you do this, you may miss important information.  If you believe that you've missed something, you can temporarily run `yum` with a higher debug level using `yum -d 2 install <a package>`.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there a way to turn this off? It's pretty annoying seeing it every time I want to install something.

Comment: I edited the answer... :-)